# Port forwarding multipass instance on windows 10 (hyper-v manager)

Tags: hyper-v, port-forwarding, windows-10, static-ip, multipass

I'm currently using Multipass on my Windows 10 machine and I'm having trouble setting up virtual switch for my Multipass instance. I want to create a mail server and send mails over the internet. Can someone guide me on how to properly configure port forwarding for Multipass on Windows 10?

I created a multipass instance `multipass launch lts --name server-web --cpus 1 --memory 1GB --disk 10GB`

I created a new virtual switch in hyper-v manager (IntelligentSofts vSwitch) [ss virtual switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz3Lo.png)

I enter in the settings of my virtual machine and change the network adapter to my virtual switch (IntelligentSofts vSwitch) [ss settings instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwC5r.png)

The problem is that everytime i do this, i cant access my multipass instance, for example: `multipass shell server-mail` give me this error

> "shell failed: ssh connection failed: 'Timeout connecting to
> server-mail.mshome.net"
> [error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONOS3.png)

This is a ss from my internet configuration ss from terminal [ss ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub45W.png)

In the end i want to use the virtual switch, use the MAC adress of my virtual machine, access my router settings, DHCP Static Lease the MAC adress to have a Static IP and then Port forward the static IP on port 25.

I also tried to assign the network at the beginning, when i launch my multipass instance. `multipass launch lts --network "IntelligentSofts vSwitch" --name server-web --cpus 1 --memory 1GB --disk 10GB`, i get the mac adress, set a stati lease on router and then port forward the ip, but it dosent work. This is what i got: [multipass info server-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHKS2.png). How i make it to use 192.168.1.112 (the IP that i leased from my router settings)

I would love to get a solution for this and also a link to some documentation.

Thank You!